# How to keep last login time fixed even page refreshed

Tags: javascript, authentication, time

I am trying to display Last Login Date&Time on my page. I am able to do it but the problem is everytime the page is refreshed or reloaded this time is changing to the time of refresh/reload. I want to keep the same login time when the login first without changing for page refresh or something like that
here is my code

```
var days = 730;
  var lastvisit=new Object();
  var firstvisitmsg=" Welcome!";
  lastvisit.subsequentvisitmsg="Last Login: <b>[displaydate]</b>";

  lastvisit.getCookie=function(Name){
  var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i");
  if (document.cookie.match(re))
  return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1];
  return'';
  }

  lastvisit.setCookie=function(name, value, days){
  var expireDate = new Date();

  var expstring=expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+parseInt(days));
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
  }

  lastvisit.showmessage = function() {
  var wh = new Date();
  if (lastvisit.getCookie("visitc") == "") {
  lastvisit.setCookie("visitc", wh, days);
  document.write(firstvisitmsg);
  }

  else {
  var lv = lastvisit.getCookie("visitc");
  var lvp = Date.parse(lv);
  var now = new Date();
  now.setTime(lvp);
  var day = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat");
  var month = new Array ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
  var dd = now.getDate();
  var dy = now.getDay();
  dy = day[dy];
  var mn = now.getMonth();
  mn = month[mn];
  yy = now.getFullYear();
  var hh = now.getHours();
  var ampm = "AM";
  if (hh >= 12) {ampm = "PM"}
  if (hh >12){hh = hh - 12};
  if (hh == 0) {hh = 12}
  if (hh < 10) {hh = "0" + hh};
  var mins = now.getMinutes();
  if (mins < 10) {mins = "0"+ mins}
  var secs = now.getSeconds();
  if (secs < 10) {secs = "0" + secs}
  var dispDate = dy + ", " + mn + " " + dd + ", " + yy + " " + hh + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + " " + ampm
  var lastlogin = lastvisit.subsequentvisitmsg.replace("\[displaydate\]", dispDate);
  document.write(lastlogin);
  }

  lastvisit.setCookie("visitc", wh, days);

  }

<div id="lastcontent" style="margin-top:-30px;margin-left:30px;font-size:72%"><script>lastvisit.showmessage();</script></div>
```

Comment: Please for the love of all that is holy format your code and use real variable names.

Comment: Save the last login timestamp on a database on the server. Serve an already formatted date to the client. PROFIT!